# Prisma Enum is undefined in Sveltekit Project

Tags: prisma, sveltekit

I have a Sveltekit project with Prisma as my ORM. In the Prisma schema I have a number of enums. I can use these enums in my server side code, e.g., in a +page.server.ts file I check the status of an object to determine what icon to display in the UI.

However, on code that is run on the browser, i.e., +page.svelte, the enums are undefined. No idea why. any pointers as to what I can do to fix?

Many thanks.

Comment: this is a known thing, follow some of these to get updated https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18699 and https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/20575